# Error:Flavor 'amazon' has no flavor dimension

Tags: android, gradle

I have **Android Studio 1.3.1**. When I open old project, with **Grandle lower 1.0.0 version**, upgrade it, change `flavorGroups => flavorDimensions, packageName => applicationId, runProguard => minifyEnabled`. And I have this error:

```
"Error:Flavor 'amazon' has no flavor dimension".
```

When I remark amazon productFlavor, the error on google. My code is:

```
    android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "20.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionName = "1.3.3"
        versionCode = 33
    }

    flavorDimensions "market", "version"

    project.archivesBaseName = "pp"

    signingConfigs {
        production {
            storeFile file("XXX")
            storePassword "XXXXXX"
            keyAlias "My App"
            keyPassword "XXXXX"
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        debug {
            minifyEnabled false
        }

        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFile 'proguard-project.txt'
            debuggable false
            signingConfig signingConfigs.production
        }
    }

    productFlavors {
        amazon {
            flavorDimensions "market"
        }
        google {
            flavorDimensions "market"
        }
        
    }

    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            def apk = output.outputFile;
            def newName = "${output.name}-${variant.mergedFlavor.versionCode}"
            if (variant.buildType.versionNameSuffix) {
                newName += "-${variant.buildType.versionNameSuffix}"
            }
            if (output.zipAlign) {
                output.zipAlign.outputFile = new File((File) apk.parentFile, newName + '-aligned.apk');
            }
            output.packageApplication.outputFile = new File((File) apk.parentFile, newName + ".apk")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: A am sorry, change flavorDimensions "market", "version" , but result is same.

Comment: Could you incorporate your comment into the question?

Comment: Done. Seems like studio don't see the string flavorDimensions "market", "version" . I change it, but no result.

Answer (score 4):

Change your configurations as below

```
flavorDimensions "market", "version"
productFlavors {
    amazon {
        flavorDimension "market"
        applicationId "com.app.amazon"
    }
    google {
        flavorDimension "market"
        applicationId "com.app.google"
    }
}
```

This has worked for me, Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

**flavorDimensions** "market" --> **flavorDimension** "market"